# State not updating until I add or remove a console log

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-state, debouncing

```
const BankSearch = ({ banks, searchCategory, setFilteredBanks }) => {
  const [searchString, setSearchString] = useState();

  const searchBanks = (search) => {
    const filteredBanks = [];
    banks.forEach((bank) => {
      if (bank[searchCategory].toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase())) {
        console.log(bank[searchCategory].toLowerCase());
        filteredBanks.push(bank);
      }
    });

    setFilteredBanks(filteredBanks);
  };
  const debounceSearch = useCallback(_debounce(searchBanks, 500), []);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (searchString?.length) {
      debounceSearch(searchString);
    } else setFilteredBanks([]);
  }, [searchString, searchCategory]);

  const handleSearch = (e) => {
    setSearchString(e.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <div className='flex'>
      <Input placeholder='Bank Search' onChange={handleSearch} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default BankSearch;
```

filteredBanks state is not updating

banks is a grandparent state which has a lot of objects, similar to that is filteredBanks whose set method is being called here which is setFilteredBanks

if I add a console log and save or remove it the state updates

Comment: Make sure you have added filterBanks state to useEffect dependency array.

Answer (score 0):

Adding or removing the console statement and saving the file, renders the function again, the internal function's state is updated returned with the (setState) callback.

(@vnm)
Adding `filteredBanks` to your dependency array won't do much because it is part of the lexical scope of the function `searchBanks`

I'm not entirely sure of the total context of this `BankSearch` or what it should be. What I do see is that there are some antipatterns and missing dependencies.

Try this:

```
export default function BankSearch({ banks, searchCategory, setFilteredBanks }) {
const [searchString, setSearchString] = useState();

const searchBanks = useCallback(
    search => {
        const filteredBanks = [];

        banks.forEach(bank => {
            if (bank[searchCategory].toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase())) {
                filteredBanks.push(bank);
            }
        });

        setFilteredBanks(filteredBanks);
    },
    [banks, searchCategory, setFilteredBanks]
);

const debounceSearch = useCallback(() => _debounce(searchBanks, 500), [searchBanks]);

useEffect(() => {
    if (searchString?.length) {
        debounceSearch(searchString);
    } else setFilteredBanks([]);
}, [searchString, searchCategory, setFilteredBanks, debounceSearch]);

const handleSearch = e => {
    setSearchString(e.target.value);
};

return (
    <div className="flex">
        <Input placeholder="Bank Search" onChange={handleSearch} />
    </div>
)}
```

It feels like the component should be a faily simple search and filter and it seems overly complicated for what it needs to do.

Again, I don't know the full context, however, I'd look into the compont architecture/structuring of the app and state.